# Port ruby solution to C++ 

Tags: c++, ruby, range

Is there any way to do this in C++ especially the range section.

```
answer = (0..999).select { |a| a%3 ==0 || a%5==0 }
puts answer.inject { |sum, n| sum+n }
```

I have created my own c++ solution but using a more standard for loop and wondered if there was a cooler way to do it?

Comment: The people who can answer this are probably experienced C++ programmers, and since that group does not necessarily overlap with Ruby programmers... what does this code do?

Comment: @Etienne de Martel It computes the sum of all integers in the range [0, 999] which are multiples of 3 or 5. The "boring" approach would be: `int s = 0; for (int i = 0; i <= 999; i++) { if ((i % 3 == 0) || (i % 5 == 0)) { s += i; } }; cout << s;` or similar.

Comment: The "cool" approach would be to use template metaprogramming. I'm sure there is a way to do it.

Comment: cooler - not conforming to the standard but achieving a sleek and stylish result.      I like to always try and learn the standard and non-standard(alternate) way of doing things.

Comment: You could probably do something with the `accumulate` algorithm and a lambda function. I came up with a cool Python solution, though: `sum(x for x in range(0, 1000) if x%3 == 0 or x%5 == 0)`.

Comment: Thank you for providing such clear example of why I love ruby. :D

Comment: @DGM: how about `(0..999).select { |a| a % 3 == 0 || a % 5 == 0 }.inject(:+)` then? :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Template metaprogramming solution:

The following assumes the lower bound of the range is 0.

```
template <int N>
struct sum
{
  static const int value = sum<N-1>::value + (N % 3 == 0 || N % 5 == 0 ? N : 0);
};

template <>
struct sum<0>
{
  static const int value = 0;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int n = sum<999>::value;
  return 0;
}
```

The following will allow you to specify a range of numbers (e.g. 0-999, 20-400). I'm not a master of template metaprogramming so I couldn't think of a cleaner solution (and I did this for my own benefit and practice).

```
template <int N, int Upper, bool IsLast>
struct sum_range_helper
{
  static const int value = (N % 3 == 0 || N % 5 == 0 ? N : 0) + sum_range_helper<N + 1, Upper, N + 1 == Upper>::value;
};

template <int N, int Upper>
struct sum_range_helper<N, Upper, true>
{
  static const int value = (N % 3 == 0 || N % 5 == 0 ? N : 0);
};

template <int Lower, int Upper>
struct sum_range
{
  static const int value = sum_range_helper<Lower, Upper, Lower == Upper>::value;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int n = sum_range<0, 999>::value;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Untested code. Uses C++ 0x feature (lambda function and iota)

```
vector<int> v(1000);

//fill the vector
iota(v.begin(),v.end(),0);

v.erase(remove_if(v.begin(),v.end(),[](int a) { return !(a%3 && a%5); }),v.end());
int sum = accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),0);
```

Comment: Even cooler would be using `generate` to populate the vector.

Comment: Or, since you're using C++11 anyway, [iota](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota).  Also, you need an erase in there.

Comment: It also needs `v.end()` in the `erase` call, and the lambda logic is backwards.

Comment: @FredLarson what do you meant by lambda logic is backwards?

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent C++ program would be:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i=0; i <= 999; i++) {
    if (i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0)
      sum += i;
  }
  cout << sum;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that was basically my for loop solution too.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a cool C version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LAMBDA(body, ...) ({ int _(__VA_ARGS__) { return (body); }; _; })

int range(int* arr, int start, int end) {
    (*arr = start) < end && range(arr + 1, start + 1, end);
}

void select(int* arr, int count, int(*fn)(int)) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
        if(!fn(arr[i]))
            arr[i] = 0;
}

int inject(int* arr, int count, int(*fn)(int,int)) {
    int acc = arr[0], i;
    for(i = 1; i < count; i++)
        acc = fn(acc, arr[i]);
    return acc;
}

int main()
{
    int numbers[1000];

    range(numbers, 1, 1000);
    select(numbers, 1000, LAMBDA(a % 3 == 0 || a % 5 == 0, a));
    printf("%d\n", inject(numbers, 1000, LAMBDA(a + b, a, b)));
}
```

http://codepad.org/eUKFAvkc